# Updating prices configurable products with Magmi

Tags: magento, magmi, configurable

I'm trying to use Magmi for updating the prices of my products. The price column is updated very fast and easy, but for the configurable products i also have to update the super attribute pricing.

The Configurable Item processor should do the trick i believed. I dont need the simples/configurale link so i set that to no and auto match off. 
I have added the following colums to my csv:

configurable_attributes : fijn_maten_ks_effen <=reference to the configurable attribute
super_attribute_pricing : maat::35 x 50 cm:0;40 x 60 cm:0;50 x 70 cm:0;60 x 70 cm:0;60 x 80 cm:0;80 x 80 cm:8

The data is on the configurable product's row. But after importing nothing happens and progress.txt is not mentionin any errors.

Does anybody have experience with his? Or has an example csv for me?

Thanx in advance! Burney

Comment: for super_attribute_pricing, you should replace "maat" (which seems not to be an attribute code) with "fijn_maten_ks_effen" which i suppose would match the dimension values you want to price. In fact the wiki is misleading, will fix it right now

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem. Works fine now. Many thanks.